# Django tutorial part 3 - NoReverseMatch at /polls/

Tags: python, html, django, python-2.7

I have been following the [Django tutorial part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03/) and am getting the following error when I attempt to view http://localhost:8000/polls/:

```
**Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'polls/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$']**
```

My files are as follows:

mysite/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

polls/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

polls/detail.html:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

polls/templates/polls/index.html:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
```

**What does this error mean?**

**How do I debug it?**

**Can you suggest a fix?**

N.b. I have seen and tried the answers to the similar questions:

[NoReverseMatch at /polls/ (django tutorial)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151816/noreversematch-at-polls-django-tutorial?rq=1)
[Django 1.8.2 -- Tutorial Chapter 3 -- Error: NoReverseMatch at /polls/ -- Python 3.4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31103954/django-1-8-2-tutorial-chapter-3-error-noreversematch-at-polls-python)
[NoReverseMatch - Django 1.7 Beginners tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645132/noreversematch-django-1-7-beginners-tutorial?rq=1)
[Django: Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336076/django-reverse-for-detail-with-arguments-and-keyword-arguments-n#19336837)
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-users/etSR78dgKBo/euSYcSyMCgAJ
[NoReverseMatch at /polls/ (django tutorial)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151816/noreversematch-at-polls-django-tutorial?rq=1)
https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/3d43gb/noreversematch_at_polls1results_in_django/

Edit, I initially missed the following question. Its excellent answer partially answers my question (how to debug) but does not cover my specific problem.

[What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The actual problem for this specific case is that `question.id` is empty

Comment: @Sayse thanks, does that mean the error is expected and I'm just not supposed to be looking at http://localhost:8000/polls/ ?

Comment: Yes, since `question.id` is empty you can see you have an empty string argument` and you don't have a url that doesn't match that. so you need to work out why that id is missing

Comment: @Sayse If you like, put that as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd think it would be better closed as a duplicate - One of the bullet points under Args and Kwargs in the duplicate points to that specific possible issue :)

Comment: @Sayse Fair enough, thanks.

Comment: @Sayse I found that I am supposed to look at localhost:8000/polls, see my answer.

Answer (score 9):

This was the problem:

polls/templates/polls/index.html should have been:

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

I had inadvertantly replaced the entire file with the following line, rather than just updating the relevant line (implied [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names)):

```
<li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
```

As stated by @Sayse in the comments, this would mean that question.id is empty resulting in the error.